# Datetime Picker Filter Exception: Call to a member function format() on bool codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

Hello I'm trying to create a filter with datetime but when I tried to use datetime I have this error :  Exception: Call to a member function format() on bool

but without time it works fine.

here's my helper code:

```
function to_sql_date($date, $datetime = false)
{
    if ($date == '' || $date == null) {
        return null;
    }

    $to_date     = 'Y-m-d';
    $from_format = get_current_date_format(true);

    $date = hooks()->apply_filters('before_sql_date_format', $date, [
        'from_format' => $from_format,
        'is_datetime' => $datetime,
    ]);

    if ($datetime == false) {
        // Is already Y-m-d format?
        if (preg_match('/^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})$/', $date)) {
            return $date;
        }

        return hooks()->apply_filters(
            'to_sql_date_formatted',
            DateTime::createFromFormat($from_format, $date)->format($to_date)
        );
    }

    if (strpos($date, ' ') === false) {
        $date .= ' 00:00:00';
    } else {
        $hour12 = (get_option('time_format') == 24 ? false : true);
        if ($hour12 == false) {
            $_temp = explode(' ', $date);
            $time  = explode(':', $_temp[1]);
            if (count($time) == 2) {
                $date .= ':00';
            }
        } else {
            $tmp  = _simplify_date_fix($date, $from_format);
            $time = date('G:i', strtotime($tmp));
            $tmp  = explode(' ', $tmp);
            $date = $tmp[0] . ' ' . $time . ':00';
        }
    }

    $date = _simplify_date_fix($date, $from_format);
    $d    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));

    return hooks()->apply_filters('to_sql_date_formatted', $d);
}
```

My Controller Code to get period for my datepicker with date range.
And my date format is DATETIME on SQL

```
private function get_where_report_period($field = 'date')
    {
        $months_report      = $this->input->post('report_months');
        $custom_date_select = '';
        if ($months_report != '') {
            if (is_numeric($months_report)) {
                // Last month
                if ($months_report == '1') {
                    $beginMonth = date('Y-m-01', strtotime('first day of last month'));
                    $endMonth   = date('Y-m-t', strtotime('last day of last month'));
                } else {
                    $months_report = (int) $months_report;
                    $months_report--;
                    $beginMonth = date('Y-m-01', strtotime("-$months_report MONTH"));
                    $endMonth   = date('Y-m-t');
                }

                $custom_date_select = 'AND (' . $field . ' BETWEEN "' . $beginMonth . '" AND "' . $endMonth . '")';
            } elseif ($months_report == 'this_month') {
                $custom_date_select = 'AND (' . $field . ' BETWEEN "' . date('Y-m-01') . '" AND "' . date('Y-m-t') . '")';
            } elseif ($months_report == 'this_year') {
                $custom_date_select = 'AND (' . $field . ' BETWEEN "' .
                date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-01-01'))) .
                '" AND "' .
                date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-12-31'))) . '")';
            } elseif ($months_report == 'last_year') {
                $custom_date_select = 'AND (' . $field . ' BETWEEN "' .
                date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date(date('Y', strtotime('last year')) . '-01-01'))) .
                '" AND "' .
                date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date(date('Y', strtotime('last year')) . '-12-31'))) . '")';
            } elseif ($months_report == 'custom') {
                $from_date = to_sql_date($this->input->post('report_from'));
                $to_date   = to_sql_date($this->input->post('report_to'));
                if ($from_date == $to_date) {
                    $custom_date_select = 'AND ' . $field . ' = "' . $this->db->escape_str($from_date) . '"';
                } else {
                    $custom_date_select = 'AND (' . $field . ' BETWEEN "' . $this->db->escape_str($from_date) . '" AND "' . $this->db->escape_str($to_date) . '")';
                }
            }
        }

        return $custom_date_select;
    }
```

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat($from_format, $date)` is failing and returning `false`. Check [`DateTime::getLastErrors()`](https://www.php.net/manual/datetime.getlasterrors.php) to see why

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in

```
if ($datetime == false) {
```

try to use else after it

```
if ($datetime == false) {
        // Is already Y-m-d format?
        if (preg_match('/^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})$/', $date)) {
            return $date;
        }

        return hooks()->apply_filters(
                        'to_sql_date_formatted',
                        DateTime::createFromFormat($from_format, $date)->format($to_date)
        );
    } else {

        if (strpos($date, ' ') === false) {
            $date .= ' 00:00:00';
        } else {
            $hour12 = (get_option('time_format') == 24 ? false : true);
            if ($hour12 == false) {
                $_temp = explode(' ', $date);
                $time = explode(':', $_temp[1]);
                if (count($time) == 2) {
                    $date .= ':00';
                }
            } else {
                $tmp = _simplify_date_fix($date, $from_format);
                $time = date('G:i', strtotime($tmp));
                $tmp = explode(' ', $tmp);
                $date = $tmp[0] . ' ' . $time . ':00';
            }
        }

        $date = _simplify_date_fix($date, $from_format);
        $d = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));

        return hooks()->apply_filters('to_sql_date_formatted', $d);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).